# Array not Recognized

Tags: java, arrays, exception, try-catch

My program is to enter 10 numbers and add them together then display the result. Then I am to divide the smaller number by the larger number and display the result. Users cannot enter characters or zero.

I am new and have been working on this for DAYS. I do not see my mistake.

Now my problem is the Variable i isn't being recognized.

I introduced an Exception (try..catch) and it wouldn't read. I tried moving things all over (I'm new, I'm guessing and seeing what does what..) I did something wrong and probably something stupidly small. I need some help and fresh eyes.

I also need to end the program when the user enters 9999. Any idea where that would go? 'Cause I'm about to break out into tears.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double[ ] digit = new double[11];
    int sum = 0;
    //Declare an array


    System.out.print("Please Enter Ten Numbers:");
    System.out.println();

    try{
    for (int i = 1; i < digit.length; i++) 
        System.out.print("Numbers " + i + ": ");
        digit[i] = (double)in.nextInt(); //Array Not recognized here
        sum += (int)digit[i];//Or recognized here
// Input the data into array from the user.

     if(digit[i]==0.0)//None of these are recognized either, what did I do? 
        {
            System.out.println("You can't enter zero. Try again");
            --i; //nope
            in.nextLine();//dispose of wrong number
        }
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){

        System.out.println("You Can Only Enter Numbers!");
            --i; //nope, not recognizing here either
            in.nextLine();//dispose of wrong input
        }

    System.out.println("Total Values in Array:"+ sum);
     // Calculate the sum and print the total


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Would you like to divide the values?");
    System.out.println("Yes or No to Exit the Program");
    String a = input.next();

     if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){   
            double [] divisionResult = new double[digit.length / 2];
//Division array declared

            for (int i = 1; i < digit.length; i += 2)
 //These are all good and recognized. No problem with the division part
            {
            double result = digit[i];
            if (result > digit[i + 1]) 
            result = result / digit[i + 1]; 
    else {
            result = digit[i + 1] / result;
        }
            divisionResult [i / 2] = result;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }
    else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
       System.exit(0);
    }
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: We need a better description than "the Variable i isn't being recognized".  You need to copy/paste the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: (Do note that you're missing a `{` after the `for` statement.  (And likely some other similar errors that would be easier to find if you were more careful with your indentation.))

Comment: That is my problem. I put the brackets around the for loop and then my try..catch don't recognize each other

Comment: Carefully match your `{` and `}` characters.  Use indentation to help you.  You should indent 4 extra spaces for every `{` you pass, and indent 4 fewer spaces when you pass the matching `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You for loop doesn't have braces around it. Only the first line below it is part of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need braces around the contents of your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to modified the attached code snippet. Hope this might help you.

```
package com.so.general;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddNumbers
{
  private static final int SIZE_OF_ARRAY = 10;
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int counter = 0;
    double sumOfTenDigits = 0.0;
    double[] digit = new double[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
    int listOfElements = digit.length;
    System.out.print("Please Enter Ten Numbers:"+"\n");
    Scanner readInputFromUser = new Scanner(System.in);

    try
    {
        for (counter=0; counter<listOfElements; counter++)
        {
            System.out.print("Numbers " + (counter+1) + ": ");
            digit[counter] = Double.parseDouble(readInputFromUser.next());
            if(digit[counter] == 0.0)
            {
                System.out.println("Zero is not allowed. Please try again.");
                System.out.print("Numbers " + (counter+1) + ": ");
                digit[counter] = Double.parseDouble(readInputFromUser.next());
            }
            sumOfTenDigits += digit[counter];
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException numberFormatExcep)
    {
        System.err.println(" You have entered other than numbers. Only numbers are allowed. Terminating the program.");
        numberFormatExcep.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Addition is: "+ sumOfTenDigits);
    System.out.println("Would you like to divide the values? Press Y to continue, any other character to terminate the program.");

    Scanner continueWithDivide = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = continueWithDivide.nextLine();

    closeScanner(readInputFromUser);
    closeScanner(continueWithDivide);

    if(readInputFromUser != null)
    {
        readInputFromUser.close();
    }

    // Always use static string literals on the left hand side. 
    // This prevents Null pointer exception.
    if("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput))
    {   
        double[] divisionResult = new double[listOfElements/2];
        for(int i=0; i<listOfElements; i+=2)
        {
           double result = digit[i];
           if (result > digit[i+1])
           {
               result = result/digit[i+1];
           }
           else 
           {
               result = digit[i+1]/result;
           }
           divisionResult[i/2] = result;
           System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.println("You have entered "+userInput+". Terminating the program.");
       System.exit(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Closed the scanner
 * @param scanner
 */
public static void closeScanner(Scanner scanner)
{
    if(scanner != null)
    {   try
        {
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException illegatStateExcep)
        {
            System.err.println("Scanner is already closed.");
            illegatStateExcep.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the below points:

- Always use proper indentation.
- Always match `{` `}`
- Even if your `if` or `for` is having only one statement, use `{` `}`.

  ```
  For example: 

  for (int counter=1; i<digit.length; i++) 
  {
     System.out.print("Numbers " + i + ": ");
  }
  ```

  Above three points will save a lot of your time if some thing goes wrong in your program.
- Use proper name for the variables and method.
- **Always close the IO resources after the use.**

  ```
  For example:

  if(scanner != null)
  {
     scanner.close();
  }
  ```